# White Space Between Nav bar and "Jumbotron"

Tags: html, css, web

I am not using bootstrap, however I want to add a "Jumbotron" like div directly underneath my Nav.

There is a small white space between  my nav bar and the div, however, and I can't figure out where it is getting the margin.

I have used the chrome element inspector, and there are no identified margins between them.

I have set the body tag to 0 margin and 0 padding, and I have tried adjusting various elements and tags to 0 and the only one that works is *, but I would like to avoid using star if possible.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Display01.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
            <title>Display 01</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <!-- Ignore the nav - It is used to modeling purposes-->
        <!-- Jump to line 27 -->
        <nav>
            <div class="toggle">
                <h3>Logo</h3>
                <i id="menu" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Services</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Portfolio</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
<!-- Begin Main Content -->
        <div class="display"><p>Test</p></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Display01.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```
.display {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
}



/*CSS Used for Navbar for Modeling Purposes*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00316b;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
ul {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
ul li:hover {
    /*background-color: #e91e63;*/
    background-color: white;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
h3 {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 0 20px 10px;
}
.menu {
    float: right;
}
.toggle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #00316b;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
    .toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        transition: 1.0s;
    }
    ul li {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I would like for the Display Div to sit flush underneath the Nav bar with no white space.

I have been trying to figure this out for some time, and I greatly appreciate the help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin is coming from the paragraph element inside the display div. You could remove that margin.

Also you can give the display div a negative margin.

You can see where the margin comes from when you use the button on the very top left of the developer tools and then hover the different elements.

Comment: That did line it up appropriately. Is setting a negative margin a recommended practice?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the css file at the top

```
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```